# Почему не выходит передать указатель на строку в функцию в качестве параметра? Правильно ли я выделяю память под строку, у которой неизвестна длина?

Tags: c, строки, указатели, динамические-массивы

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
FILE *f_out, *f_in;

void output_0(char *stroka){
    int i,n;
    while (stroka[i] != '!'){
            i++;
            n = i;
        }
        for (i=0; i<=n; i++){
            if (stroka[i] == 'ю'){
                printf("YES");
            } else {
                printf("NO");
            }
        }
}
void output_1(char *stroka){
    f_out = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    int i,n;
    while (stroka[i] != '!'){
            i++;
            n = i;
        }
        for (i=0; i<=n; i++){
            if (stroka[i] == 'ю'){
                fprintf(f_out, "YES");
            } else {
                fprintf(f_out, "NO");
            }
        }
}


int main (void){
int in, out, next, n, i;
system("chcp 1251");
char *stroka;

    do{
        printf("input from console - 0 or from file - 1? ");
        scanf ("%d", &in);
        printf("output from console - 0 or from file - 1? ");
        scanf("%d", &out);

        if (in ==0){
            printf("Введите строку: ");
            stroka = malloc( sizeof(*stroka) * 64 );
            scanf("%s", *stroka);
        } else if (in == 1){
            f_in = fopen("in.txt", "r");
            stroka = malloc( sizeof(*stroka) * 64 );
            fscanf(f_in, "%s", *stroka);
        } else {
                printf("ОШИБКА!");
        }

        if (out == 0){
                output_0(stroka);
        } else if (out == 1){
                output_1(stroka);
        } else {
                printf("ОШИБКА!");
        }
        printf("\n\nNEXT - 1, EXIT - 0? ");
        scanf("%d", &next);
    } while (next !=0);
    free(stroka);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что "не выходит передать указатель на строку в функцию в качестве параметра"?

Comment: либо проблема в выделении памяти, либо в передаче параметров, я не знаю.

Comment: У вас в коде множество проблем, но к "передаче указатель на строку в функцию" они не имеют никакого отношения.

Comment: ага, спасибо
корявенькая программка, согласна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

взять строку неизвестной длины можно так

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

char *getstring(FILE *f)
{
    size_t size = 4, idx = 0;
    char *buf = malloc(size);

    if (!buf)
        return NULL;

    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
    {
        if (idx == size - 1)
        {
            size *= 2;
            char *tmp = realloc(buf, size);
            if (!tmp)
                return NULL;
            buf = tmp;
        }
        buf[idx++] = ch;
    }
    if (idx == 0 && ch == EOF)
        return NULL;

    if (idx > 0 && idx < size - 1)
    {
        char *tmp = realloc(buf, idx + 1);
        if (!tmp)
            return NULL;
        buf = tmp;
    }

    buf[idx] = '\0';
    return buf;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *s;
    while((s = getstring(stdin)))
    {
        printf("%s\n", s);
        free(s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проблема в строке

```
scanf("%s", *stroka);
```

Вы передаете тип char, вместо указателя. Попробуйте передать указатель.

```
scanf("%s", stroka);
```

Аналогично с `fscanf`.

---

**Правка**

Данный код работает исправно при использовании ASCII. *(mingw32-gcc 8.1.0)*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int getfrom(const char* /* __restrict__ */ name, const char* /* __restrict__ */ mode, char* /* __restrict__ */ buffer) {
    FILE* fin = fopen(name, mode);

    fscanf(fin, "%s", buffer);
    fclose(fin);

    return strlen(buffer);
}

void output_file(char* buffer) {
    FILE* fout = fopen("out.txt", "w");

    while (*buffer == '!') buffer++;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++)
        if (buffer[i] == 'w')
            fprintf(fout, "YES");
        else
            fprintf(fout, "NO");

    fclose(fout);
}

void output_print(char* buffer) {
    while (*buffer == '!') buffer++;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++)
        if (buffer[i] == 'w')
            printf("YES");
        else
            printf("NO");
    printf("\n");
}


int main(void) {
    while (1) {
        int fin;
        printf("Use file input? (1/0): ");
        scanf("%d", &fin);
        int fout;
        printf("Use file output? (1/0): ");
        scanf("%d", &fout);

        char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 64);

        if (fin)
            getfrom("in.txt", "r", buffer);
        else {
            printf("Input (max 64): ");
            scanf("%s", buffer);
        }

        if (fout)
            output_file(buffer);
        else
            output_print(buffer);

        free(buffer);

        int continue_;
        printf("Continue? (1/0): ");
        scanf("%d", &continue_);

        if (!continue_)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: точно! сейчас проверю

Comment: нет, не выводит ничего

Comment: Странно, проверено на gcc 8.1.0, именно это и вызвало проблему.

Comment: у меня CodeBlocks....... эх

Comment: а эта строчка правильная? stroka = malloc( sizeof(*stroka) * 64 );

Comment: @АлияГафурова это Вы меня проверяете? Нет, неправильная.

Comment: а в чем ошибка?

Comment: @АлияГафурова Не заметил сразу, я не ас в С, но в строке  `malloc(sizeof(*stroka) * 64)` замените `*stroka` на `char`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Утром попробую запустить

Answer (score 1):

Я бы советовал использовать нечто подобное:

```
#define LEN 1024

char * readString (FILE * file) {
    char buf [LEN];
    char * ret;

    if (fgets (buf, LEN, file) == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    /* +1 для завершающего символа '\0' */
    ret = malloc (strlen (buf) + 1);

    if (ret == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    return strcpy (ret, buf);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void output_0(char *stroka){
    int i = 0,n; // !!!

stroka = malloc( sizeof(char) * 64 ); // что такое 64?
```

Comment: stroka = malloc( char * 64 ); // что такое 64?
честно, сама не пойму

Comment: т.е. malloc позволяет выделять память каждому новому вводимому символу, следовательно надо умножать на sizeof(char)?

Comment: @АлияГафурова не каждому, а всем шестидесяти четырем сразу

Comment: а как мне сделать, чтобы нормально выделялась память под строку неизвестной длины?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` - всегда и во всех системах на сегодняшний день == `1`, умножение без смысла, только в демонстрационно-обучающих целей.

Answer (score 0):

```
В итоге сделала так:

#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void output_0(char* str){
    int i, n=0;
    for (i=0; i<=strlen(str); i++){
        if (str[i] == '!'){
            n = i;
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++){
        if (str[i] == 'ю'){printf("YES");}
        else {printf("NO");}
    }
}
void output_1(char* str, FILE* file_out){
    int i,n=0;
    for (i=0; i<=strlen(str); i++){
        if (str[i] == '!'){
            n = i;
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++){
        if (str[i] == 'ю'){fprintf(file_out,"YES");}
        else {fprintf(file_out, "NO");}
    }
}


int main (){
int in, out, next, i;
system("chcp 1251");
char ch;

    do{
        char* file_in_str = malloc(1);
        char* file_out_str = malloc(1);
        char* str = malloc(1);

        printf("input from console - 0 or from file - 1? ");
        scanf ("%d", &in);
        printf("output from console - 0 or from file - 1? ");
        scanf("%d", &out);

        if (in ==0){
            printf("Введите строку: ");
            getchar();
            for (i=0; (ch = getchar()) != '\n';){
                str = realloc(str, i+1);
                str[i] = ch;
                i++;
            }
        } else if (in == 1){
            printf("Введите адрес файла: ");
            getchar();
            for (i=0; (ch = getchar()) != '\n';){
                file_in_str = realloc(file_in_str, i+1);
                file_in_str[i] = ch;
                i++;
            }
            if (i == 0) file_in_str = "in.txt";
            else file_in_str[i] = '\0';

            FILE* file_in = fopen(file_in_str, "r");
            fgets(str, 100, file_in);
            fclose(file_in);
        } else {
                printf("ОШИБКА!");
        }

        if (out == 0){
                output_0(str);
        } else if (out == 1){
            printf("Введите адрес файла: ");
            for (i=0; (ch = getchar()) != '\n';) {
                file_out_str = realloc(file_out_str, i+1);
                file_out_str[i] = ch;
                i++;
            }
            if (i == 0) file_out_str = "out.txt";
            else file_out_str[i] = '\0';

            FILE* file_out = fopen(file_out_str, "w+");
            output_1(str, file_out);
            fclose(file_out);
        } else {
                printf("ОШИБКА!");
        }
        free(file_in_str);
        free(file_out_str);
        free(str);
        printf("\n\nNEXT - 1, EXIT - 0? ");
        scanf("%d", &next);
    } while (next !=0);
    return 0;
}
```